# .NET core Windows OS requirements

Tags: .net-core

In the past, .NET framework versions have come with information about which operating systems they can be installed on. For example, the download page for [.NET 4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851) lists Windows XP SP3, Windows Vista SP1 and Windows 7 SP1 among others.

However, I can't seem to find this information on the [.NET Core download page](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download#core). On which Windows versions can .NET core be deployed?

Answer (score 2):

Found it on the [.NET core roadmap](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md):

- Windows Client:   Windows 7 SP1 - Windows 10
- Windows Server:   Windows 2008 R2 SP1 - Windows 2016